# calibre reader automatic edits to epub documents

Tags: epub

It is widely known (see [How to delete Calibre ePub bookmarks](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/2603/)), though not to my knowledge documented, that Calibre makes modifications to EPUB documents even without the user's choosing to edit them.

The best-known among these modifications is the insertion of a file named `calibre_bookmarks.txt` into the `META-INF/` directory.

Does the application make any other modifications in this context?

I see the word `calibre` in style names in various CSS files in EPUB documents that also contain the bookmarks. Is this structure more likely to result from surreptitious editing of the document by the reader application, or is it more likely to result from the document originally being created by the Calibre editor?

Asked differently, if given an EPUB document, how might one comprehensively test whether the Calibre reader had made modifications to the `.epub` file subsequent to it being originally published by the author?